# Restore Production to Dev Different logical file name

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I am trying to setup a nightly job to restore Development from a Production backup every night.  Issue I am hitting is the logical file name on production is different on development.  I am trying to restore and use move to set the file name.

Error I am receiving is 'Logical file 'BICUAT2' is not part of database 'BCIUAT'

```
Restore database BCIUAT
from disk = '\\ServerIP\SQLBackups\BICAP1\BICUAT\BICUAT_20180131220212.bak'
with recovery,
move 'BICUAT2'
to 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DEV\MSSQL\DATA\BICUAT',
move 'BICUAT2_log'
to 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.DEV\MSSQL\DATA\BICUAT_log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the logical filenames in a RESTORE.  You can only specify different file locations for each file with MOVE ... TO.  RESTORE can *also* not split or combine logical files or filegroups, or grow or shrink files.

A full restore always creates a database with exactly the same number of filegroups, files, and file sizes as the database that was backed-up.